# Installing Ubuntu on a spare SSD connected externally to a Windows laptop

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, system-installation, software-installation

I have a personal laptop running Windows 10 and I would like to use Linux(Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) without installing it on my primary hard disk.

I recently bought an additional SSD drive and thinking of externally connecting it to my laptop via eSATA or through SATA to USB adapter. Ideally, I would like to install linux on this disk, so I can keep it clean and isolated. Then, I'd like to setup dual boot on my laptop.

Is this configuration possible? If so, could you please advise or direct me to a documentation page on how I can set this up?

Also, with this setup, will I be able to make Ubuntu portable, such that can I unplug the SSD when I'm carrying my laptop around and plug it back when needed?

If I plug in the SSD on another windows laptop, would it still work?

Or, should I drop this plan altogether and try to install and run Ubuntu from a USB flash drive instead?

My laptop has 2nd gen i3 processor with 4GB RAM and 128GB SSD. It runs Windows 10 smoothly.

Comment: This should work. You’ll just need to enter desired partition scheme manually and make sure to not install GRUB to your internal disk.

Comment: Is system UEFI or BIOS, or more correctly is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. If 2nd gen i3 then hardware probably is UEFI. Better to use eSATA as USB will not support trim.

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is possible. Remember that you will need to configure the bios to boot from the ssd.
It is not necessary, but if you want to access Windows you must make **sudo update grub** every time you change computer to update the bootloader. 
it also may need to install additional drivers from the wizard for each laptop.
Remember that if you want compatibility with older computers should choose the 32-bit version

Comment: Additionally, if you switch machines, the SSD would have to always be the `second` hard drive.

Comment: OP doesn't have to update-grub if he simply boots the drive from the BIOS boot options- F10, 8, Del, etc. Some Legacy BIOSes will have issues if you set the portable SSD first, and then remove it to use on other computers (no bootable media found).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that! It's a nice idea.

When you normally install Ubuntu you install "grub" which boots up ubuntu. <s>In your situation I don't advise you to install grub.</s> No install it! Just make sure you install it on the ssd itself!

When you want to boot to windws you boot normally. When you want to want to boot Ubuntu just connect your ssd, then press *(depending on your computer)* (probably <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>F11</kbd>) you press that key to bring up the boot menu. Then you choose to boot from the SSD.

You install it on the SSD very normally ([see here](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop))

Comment: The portable SSD is the fixed Ubuntu installation location. Therefore, Grub is highly recommended to be installed *on the SSD*.

Comment: @PatrickNegus so would it work even if he disconnects and reconnects the ssd? or if he connects it to another usb port?

Comment: If you install Grub *on the SSD*, yes, it will work on all other computers and/or USB ports given that OP selects the Portable SSD in the BIOS boot options.

Comment: ooooh right! that's not what I had in mind. I only thought about installing it on the machine's drive LOL :D @PatrickNegus